# Where are MSI Motherboard Error Codes defined?

Tags: motherboard, bios

Each time I boot my PC my MSI motherboard takes it's time, sometimes up to 10 minutes to boot! It shows a few error codes, listed below, same each time -

**Question**

- Where are these error codes defined, in detail?

**Observed Error Codes**

- "92"
- "A2"

**Motherboard**:

- [MSI X99A Gaming 7 v3.0 (MS-7885)](https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/X99A-GAMING-7.html)

  - [Manual](http://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/E7885v3.1.zip)
  - ['Quick Guide'](http://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/9s_QIG.zip)

**Thoughts**

- On [p.1-37 of Chapter 1 in section 'Debug Code LED Table'](http://justinreina.com/misc/17_04_01_MSI/Debug%20Code%20LED%20Table.pdf) there are 'Post Codes' listed.

  - '92' is listed as a "PCI bus initialization'
  - 'A2' is listed as a 'Onboard devices Initialize and Detect (USB/ SATA/
    SCSI……)'. Is this it? If this is, what lovely naming, LED debug codes... ;0
- If these are the codes, which I think they may be, what do they exactly mean...? There are 14 options (9A-A7,B4) for 'onboard devices' error, for example!

Comment: Yes; Both of those errors would lead to long hardware initializing errors or times.  Not all error codes are defined, some are used by MSI to diagnose problems, only what is published are defined

Comment: that mean it is time to replace the board?